# Tomcat and HSQL java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, hsqldb

**First of all I included the `hsqldb.jar` to my classpath**

Here is the screenshot of this damn driver

[image]

---

However I get error `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver`

Here is my `init` method

```
public void init() throws ServletException {

            PoolProperties p = new PoolProperties();
            p.setUrl("jdbc:hsqldb: . . . \\data");
            p.setDriverClassName( "org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver" );
            p.setUsername( "sa" );
            p.setPassword( "" );
            dataSource = new org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSource( p );

    }
```

I don't understand why this is happening. I included the `hsqldb.jar` with `Eclipse`. I also   checked the `classpath` file `<classpathentry kind="lib" path="C:/ . . . /hsqldb.jar"/>`

Why do I get this error ? I connected to HSQL many times from regular java applications. Now that I try to connect by overwriting `Tomcat` init method it throws an error

Comment: Make sure you are using correct jar path. Also make sure you have compiled the project.

Comment: I added a screenshot of that driver and eclipse compiles everything

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you meant to use the class name `org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver`. You have `org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver`, which is non-standard in a few ways.

Comment: Thank you. I tried that too  `Unable to load class: org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCDriver from ClassLoader:java.net.URLClassLoader@ec7c94`

Comment: I'm not sure how Eclipse ensures that JARs are in the right place for deployment into Tomcat. Where does your JDBC JAR file end up when Tomcat launches? You may have to copy `hsqldb.jar` into Tomcat's `lib/` directory manually.

Comment: Thank you I tried copying it to `lib/` but tomcat was not even able to start. When I removed that `hsqldb.jar` the tomcat started as normal

Comment: That `lib/` directory does have `tomcat-jdbc.jar`

Comment: That's not the JAR file you need. `tomcat-jdbc.jar` contains a JDBC connection pool implementation, not a JDBC driver. You need to put the JDBC driver for HSQLDB into the `lib/` directory.

Comment: Yes. I copied this jar `hsqldb.jar` into that `lib/` and Tomcat threw an error and was not able to start. Then I deleted `hsqldb.jar` from `lib/` and Tomcat started as normal

Comment: @Melinda Would you care to share the error you got?